# How to make ubuntu install avoid bad blocks?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, 64-bit

I know this may be a duplicate, but I think my case is unique enough to warrant another question. I have a 320gb 7200 rpm hdd with the last half of the disk basically perfect, but the first half has (I think) some physical surface imperfections from being knocked around in a car while running. I checked the disk after that incident, and it said the disk was failing. I continued after that, and while it still said the disk was failing, it didn't change, nor did I have any problems with anything other than the first half of the disk. I have some screenshots taken a few minutes ago of what the disks application says about the disk from the SMART data. I switched the disk from an old 32 bit computer to a 64 bit one, and want to install 64 bit ubuntu without wiping out the 32 bit zorin os on the second to last partition. The ubuntu installer fails when I try to install on the first half of the disk, where part way through installation it says I/O error, and the installer crashes. I want to know how I can make the installer avoid the bad spots and install regardless. Here is a bit of what the smart data says: reallocated sector count: 0 sectors, threshold 5, worst 1, normalized 1, reallocation count: 4459, normalized 9, worst 9, threshold 0, uncorrectable sectors: 0

Comment: If you repair your disk `fsck` it can repair (disable) bad blocks. I do not advise to keep using your disk because these things go from bad to worse pretty fast... back up what you need and replace the disk.

Comment: How do I use fsck in this situation? The drive I want to fix is dev sda7

Comment: Really --- I wouldn't touch that disk with a three feet pole. It's a call for data loss. And on an aside, James Joyce can get by with the kind of paragraph in your question, but we common mortal should try to format it a bit ;-)

Comment: sorry about that. :p. I tried installing to an sd card I had, and it failed in the exact same place, I thought I verified the disk, but I guess my iso download was corrupted. It's only the first quarter of the disk that has errors that I found with gparted with a surface scan, I'll try and install on the second quarter. Sorry about the formatting, I was just really tired after getting out of school(first day of summer for me in Sunapee.) I'll try and redownload the iso with a downloader instead of chrome.

Comment: I don't want to repair the disk, and ive ordered a new one, I just want to see how much more life I can eek out of this drive. I just realized that it was a bad ISO, the damage to the disk is minimal enough that it can survive perfectly well on a desk without motion.

Comment: why was this marked as duplicate? the one linked deals with something I've already tried, and did not even come CLOSE to answering this, I have a disk with errors that CANNOT be repaired, I just want the installer to evade them while installing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue was not a write error with the installer having issues with bad blocks, I found it was an issue with a bad ISO download, and this a corrupt DVD. I re downloaded the image and re burned it, it installed perfectly. I have a new disk coming, but I don't think it is necessary, I'll just install windows on the other drive and keep my Linux disk from getting bumped around too much. The surface scan I just did showed that the damage was limited to a very small part of the disk, and it has not increased with time, thank god. thanks everyone for helping me narrow it down to a bad download.